# Get the row from previous load date in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, window-functions, rank

I have a table in BigQuery with 2 dates, the reception date and the date load date. I need to
set a mark on the last LOAD_DATE before the RECEPCION_DATE and another mark, on the first load of the same day.
I've been trying with Windows Functions, but it is not working.
Any idea about how this can be done?

Thanks!

```
RECEPTION_DATE   LOAD_DATE            LastLoadBeforeDate    FirstLoadOnDate
23-02-2024       25-02-2024 8:07        0                   0
23-02-2024       24-02-2024 16:06       0                   0
23-02-2024       24-02-2024 12:07       0                   0
23-02-2024       24-02-2024 8:07        0                   0
23-02-2024       23-02-2024 16:06       0                   0
23-02-2024       23-02-2024 12:07       0                   0
23-02-2024       23-02-2024 8:07        0                   1
23-02-2024       22-02-2024 16:06       1                   0
23-02-2024       22-02-2024 12:07       0                   0
23-02-2024       22-02-2024 8:07        0                   0
23-02-2024       21-02-2024 16:06       0                   0
23-02-2024       21-02-2024 12:07       0                   0
```